# Syntax needed to make two SCSS mixins containing media queries share the same CSS code

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, multiple-instances, scss-mixins

I have the following mixin containing media queries:

```
@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
    @if $breakpoint == phone {
        @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) { @content };    //600px
    }
    @if $breakpoint == tab-port {
        @media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) { @content };     //900px
    }
    @if $breakpoint == tab-land {
        @media only screen and (max-width: 75em) { @content };    //1200px
    }
    @if $breakpoint == big-desktop {
        @media only screen and (min-width: 112.5em) { @content };    //1800px
    }
}
```

I would like to share the same CSS properties for two of those media queries but I am not succeeding in doing so. I've written it as follows but it doesn't work.

```
    @include respond(phone),
    @include respond(tab-port) {
        some CSS properties
   }
```

I was wondering if anyone could help. Thanks in advance for doing so!

Answer (score 0):

You would create another mixin with the properties you want them both to share, and then use that in each include.

In mixin files:

```
@mixin two-device {
  @media (max-width: 37.5em) {
    @content;
  }
  @media (max-width: 56.25em) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And then you should use it:

```
  @include two-device {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@mixin respond($breakpoint) {
    @if $breakpoint == phone {
        @media only screen and (min-width: 37.5em) { @content; }    //600px
    }
    @else if $breakpoint == tab-port {
        @media only screen and (min-width: 56.25em) { @content;}     //900px
    }
    @else if $breakpoint == tab-land {
        @media only screen and (min-width: 75em) { @content; }    //1200px
    }
    @else $breakpoint == big-desktop {
        @media only screen and (min-width: 112.5em) { @content; }    //1800px
    }
}
```